# How do I make this simple CSS animation work? (orbiting circles)

Tags: css

I'm trying learn how to create a CSS animation of multiple circles orbiting another circle in the center (I only need it to work in Chrome)

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxvBve?editors=1100

I'm having troubles making them orbit in different planes and at different angles relative to the viewer. I'm not sure what's the simplest and more optimal way to do it. Should I use `rotate()` or something else?

Comment: Did you look at the example you posted? They are scaling not rotating at all. Do you want them to actually orbit a circle or appear to?

Comment: @DanielTate yes, I want them to actually orbit. I just don't know how to do it. Right now they look like they orbit at 0deg angle to viewer, but I want them to actually orbit at different angles (planes) to the viewer. (I also want them to scale when they are closer to the viewer, this is why I added scale)

Answer (score 2):

I modified your sample as noted below. It allows for a crisscross movement of the electrons. I think if you adjust the left, right and top values in movementLeft and movementRight in other ways you could achieve other angles as needed:

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
}

#atom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.3);
}

#nucleus {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
}


.electron1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: movementLeft 2s ease-in-out infinite, size 2s linear infinite;
}

.electron2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: movementRight 2s ease-in-out infinite, size 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes movementLeft {
  0% { left: -150px; top: -150px }
  50% { left: 150px; top: 150px}
  100% { left: -150px; top:-150px }
}

@-webkit-keyframes movementRight {
  0% { right: -150px; top: -150px }
  50% { right: 150px; top: 150px}
  100% { right: -150px; top:-150px }
}

@-webkit-keyframes size {
  0% { transform: scale(1) }
  25% { transform: scale(2) }
  75% { transform: scale(1) }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="atom">
  <div id="nucleus"></div>
  <div class="electron1"></div>
  <div class="electron2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      background: #222;
    }
    
    #atom {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.3);
    }
    
    #nucleus {
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
      position: absolute;
     background: #999;
     border-radius: 100%;
    }
    
    
    .electron1 {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 100%;
      -webkit-animation: movementLeft 2s ease-in-out infinite, size 2s linear infinite;
    }
    
    .electron2 {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 100%;
      -webkit-animation: movementRight 2s ease-in-out infinite, size 2s linear infinite;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes movementLeft {
      0% { left: -150px; top: -150px }
      50% { left: 150px; top: 150px}
      100% { left: -150px; top:-150px }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes movementRight {
      0% { right: -150px; top: -150px }
      50% { right: 150px; top: 150px}
      100% { right: -150px; top:-150px }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes size {
      0% { transform: scale(1) }
      25% { transform: scale(2) }
      75% { transform: scale(1) }
    }
```

```html
    


    <div id="atom">
      <div id="nucleus"></div>
      <div class="electron1"></div>
      <div class="electron2"></div>
    </div>
```